# Circular Relationship in Database Design

Tags: database-design

I have a database with 4 tables (there are more, but only 4 are causing the problem). The rules are: a Model has 1 to many tasks. A Task has one to many Sets. A SuperSet has one to many Sets and a Model has one to many SuperSets. A SuperSet is basically just a list of sets. The design has led to a circular looking dependency graph like the following:

```
Models <--------------------------- SuperSets
   ^                                    ^
   |                                    |
   |                                    |
Tasks  <---------------------------- Sets
```

I've read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38655/Prevent-Circular-References-in-Database-Design , but I can't get rid of any of the tables, and the second example is a different case than mine. I've read that circular relationships aren't desirable but I don't really see any way around this one. Is this even a problem, and if so how can I fix it?

Comment: Assuming that you put the correct directional arrows in your sample diagram, I do not see any circularity.  Models have Tasks and SuperSets, Tasks have Sets, and SuperSets have Sets.

Comment: According to the link I posted, this sort of design is bad. I wanted to poll SO and see what the consensus was

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As has been said, there is no circular reference in your model.  The arrows do not go around in a circle.

Perhaps you're worried that `Sets` can reach it's grandparent `Models` through two different parents.  This is a legitimate concern which can be resolved by ensuring that the primary key of `Models` is part of the primary key of the other three tables.

With foreign keys in place, this ensures that each row in `Sets` belongs to exactly one model.

So the design would be as follows:

- `Model` table has primary key of `ModelId`.
- `Tasks` table has a primary key of `ModelId` and something else, say `TaskNumber`.  `ModelId` is also a foreign key to `Models`.
- `SuperSets` table has a primary key of `ModelId` and something else, say `SuperSetNumber`.  `ModelId` is also a foreign key to `Models`.
- `Sets` has a primary key of `ModelId`, `TaskNumber`, and `SuperSetNumber`.  It has foreign keys to be `Tasks` and `SuperSets`.

In this design because the single column `Sets.ModelId` is part of two foreign keys,  the data integrity is enforced.

Answer (score 6):

Your design is not circular.

There's `Models` at the top level with 2 child tables `Tasks` and `Supersets`. Then there's `Sets` on the lowest level. None of the levels go back to the higher level table.

This is fine and won't cause any problems.