# How to solve the circular relationship in form

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access-2016

I came across a problem when trying to build a dropdown list in a form.

I have following tables:

1. "carrier", it contains an ID (primary key)
2. "product", it contains an ID (primary key) and carrier ID (which is a foreign key from table "carrier") and product name
3. "shareclass", it contains an ID (primary key)  and class type
4. "product + shareclass", it contains an ID (primary key), product ID (foreign key) and shareclass ID (foreign key)
5. "Living Benefit", it contains an ID (primary key), living benefit name and carrier ID (foreign key)
6. "Product + shareclass + Living Benefit", it contains an ID (primary key) and product + shareclass ID (foreign key) and living benefit ID (foreign key)

I have created a query that select **carrier ID, product name** from **table.product**,product **ID, shareclassID**, from **table.product+shareclass**, **class type** from **table.shareclass**, and **living benefit name** from **table.living benefit** left join **table.product+shareclass+living benefit**.

Now I want to create a form that populates the last table, which is "product + shareclass + Living Benefit", and my source is from my query. I want my **"product + shareclass ID"** to be a combo box that is dependent on the **carrier** (**requery** after I update **carrier ID**)

And here is the problem. Because in my query, my **carrier** depends on **product+shareclass ID**, and now I want to choose "product+shareclass ID" based on the **carrier ID**, there is a circular relationship.

I was thinking adding a **Carrier ID** to my last table **table.product+shareclass+LB**, but does it break the **Third Normal Form**?

Is there any suggestions on how I can avoid the circular relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521851) and see if it is pertinent to yours. It looks as if your problem as well is one of multiple paths, not circular relationships.

Comment: Hi, I think my question really is, if you have table A with IDA (one to many) table B with IDB. How do you create a form that has a combo list for IDB that is based on the selection of IDA. The problem is every time I select IDA, Access won't allow me to select B unless I save the record first, because my B populates A

Comment: I guess I should just use sub form. But is there any other more creative way?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with Access, just with database design.